# Google Compute Selenium intermittent connection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-compute-engine, google, selenium

I'm trying out Google Compute. I have an issue I never saw on AWS.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 / Codeception / Selenium / Chromedriver / Chrome to run a simple acceptance test. The thing is, it fails randomly. Without changing anything, I can either fail or pass the test.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I never had this happen on AWS. No clue. Any ideas? Pretty certain it's Google, not me. It seams I have to sometime "wake up" the outbound HTTP in google cloud. Is this a real phenomenon?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the Driver version to 80.0.3987.149.

Comment: According to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads I'm at the highest version. I don't think they keep Chrome and Chromedriver exactly the same. I think I'm using the latest versions. I'm also pretty sure that this is Google, since I don't have the problem on AWS or my local machine.

Comment: But I don't have any other connection problems, except via Selenium. I have a website running on the box, and no problems.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification John.

I think the best way to move this issue forward is to report this issue to the Chromedriver bug-tracker [1], providing all the reproduction steps that led you to experiencing the issue.
___
[1]
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list